# Is there a benefit to calling a function within a function?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I'm following a tutorial on MDN for Javascript and they add an `onclick` handler to a button and then call a function within a function:

```
myButton.onclick = function() {
setUserName();
}
```

I tried assigning the event to the function directly and it still worked, so I wondered if there's any good reason to do it their way.

Comment: Generally you do that when you need to modify the parameters in some regard, or need to call multiple functions in order.

Comment: I don't understand the bit about the parameters but I do see the reason around calling multiple functions.

Answer (score 2):

If the function doesn't care about the event object that gets passed as the first argument, no. It bloats the code, creates an extra object in memory and has no benefit.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by event object and first argument, sorry - can you clarify please.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a lambda function for handling an event is a dirty way of coding, IMO. It's much cleaner and safer to separate interface and actual processing.

If you need to do something complicated in your handler, it's just as easy to define a properly named function to do the job, and assign the handler to it.

Once you have done this terrible naming effort, you can do whatever you want with your handler, including testing it by feeding dummy events, reusing it for handling events from different buttons, etc.

On the other hand, web pages that will probably not be around for more than a few weeks or months at most are not the best place for clean coding anyway...

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie and didn't understand what a lambda function is or what you meant by interface.

Comment: a lambda function is just a function without a name. The interface is basically what you see (buttons, divs and such) while the processing is the algorithmic part of the code (what you do with your data once the user triggered an action through the interface). For instance you can do the same processing if the user clicks a button or presses some hotkey.